Why θεός (in lower case)? (greek)
I've already spent a good time reading the New Testament, and I can't find any passage in which θεός is in uppercase. Why this is the case? (More precisely, I would like to know something such as historical context, etc.) Below I show a passage from Corinthians II as an example:


Why would you expect it to be in uppercase?

Paul makes reference to a god of a monotheistic religion; therefore, it is a proper noun in his writings, and in greek it would be written in uppercase. If he were using this noun in a polytheistic context, I would expect it to be in lowercase, but this is evidently not the case here.

@IesusHominumSalvator Those are English (and Modern Greek?) rules. Ancient Greek had no such rules.

If you search this site for "capitalization", we've gone into it a good bit with Latin here. I'm not sure off-hand whether we've touched upon Greek capitalization though.

And now this one. Does my answer on this question answer your concerns, too? If not, can you edit it further to clarify what still might be confusing? Thanks.

The excerpt is 2 Corinthians 4:2; the word θεός occurs in the sense that modern practice dictates upper case. Indeed,the 1904 text published by the Ecumenical Patriarchate reads:

ἀλλ’ ἀπειπάμεθα τὰ κρυπτὰ τῆς αἰσχύνης, μὴ περιπατοῦντες ἐν πανουργίᾳ
μηδὲ δολοῦντες τὸν λόγον τοῦ Θεοῦ, ἀλλὰ τῇ φανερώσει τῆς ἀληθείας
συνιστῶντες ἑαυτοὺς πρὸς πᾶσαν συνείδησιν ἀνθρώπων ἐνώπιον τοῦ Θεοῦ.

The Greek upper case/lower case distinction originated with the use of minuscule style as opposed to majuscule/uncial around 9th-10th centuries A.D.
Hence, the excerpt is either from an earlier text or from one following the earlier style.
